# What can I use if I don't know if my PCs remember an urban route?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, knowledge-check

In our current adventures my PCs are in a specific very large City. By searching, they found a specific black market shop, the route leading to which was a bit complicated.

Can they roll an intelligence check to determine if they remember the complex route, or do I have to describe the roads one by one until they find it again (which is not a problem)?

I try to run the campaign as realistic as possible and this situation is like a common real life problem. We tend to use marks along the way (shops, signs) to remember specific routes, but a lot of times we fail because we don't remember minor details (which is described as high check).

Comment: "the route leading to which was a bit complicated", how did the PCs find it in the first place? Did you ask for a check? Did someone guide them there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DMG (p.237) says, that **Intelligence checks are used for memory and reason**, so this would be a fitting check.

> [...] or do I have to describe the roads one by one until they find it again (which is not a problem)

This would be a *"test the characters, not the players"* situation. I would strongly discourage you from doing so, except you aim for exactly that.

> We tend to use marks along the way (shops, signs) to remember specific routes, but a lot of times we fail because we don't remember minor details (which is described as high check).

Maybe give them advantage on the Intelligence check if they describe you how they remember the way or let them use **Investigation checks to find their way back on track if they get lost.**

All in all, if there are no consequences for failed checks, I would like to refer to the **DMG (p.237)** which recommends that you assume, if they have got the time, they succeed automatically taking ten times the normal amount of time needed to get there.

Comment: Agreed, Int Check is a shoe-in for this sort of thing, and this is exactly what taking 10/20 was invented for, assuming there's not a serious penalty for showing up late.

Answer (score 2):

## What is the consequence of failure?

Let's assume that they fail. What happens now? I'm guessing that they will just use whatever method caused them to find it in the first place to find it in the second place. If so: **why are we wasting valuable playing time on this?**

Only if you decide that there *is* a consequence for failure should you bother making any type of check at all.

### [Old school or new school?](http://www.lulu.com/items/volume_63/3019000/3019374/1/print/3019374.pdf)

Do you want to test the players (old school) or the characters (new school) or a bit of both [see Zen Moment 2]?

**Neither method is better than the other: it is purely a matter of *your* group's preference!**

If you want to test the players then describe what they see and they have to rely on their own memories. If you want to test the characters then an Intelligence check is appropriate with whatever proficiency the player can make a case for - Perception and Investigation spring to mind.